# Idiomatic way to strip/check :ok and pipe second arg

Tags: elixir

I like pipes and Elixir likes pipes, but it also seems to be common to return {:ok, actual_return_value}. Is there an idiom for handling this with pipes?

I am studying "Programming Elixir" right now, and the following solution to an exercise might be possible but incomplete.

```
File.cwd()
|> IO.puts()
```

I am not looking for this solution:

```
{:ok, ret} = File.cwd()
IO.puts(ret)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends how you want to handle errors.

If you wanted to branch on the return value, you could use a [`case`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#case/2) or a [`with`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#with/1) or something like that. If you put it in a private function, it allows for piping (you can pipe in directly, but it gets ugly quick).

```rb
with {:ok, pwd} <- File.cwd() do
  IO.puts(pwd)
end
```

If getting a response other than an ok tuple is exceptional, you could use the bang versions of functions.

```rb
File.cwd!()
|> IO.puts()
```

If your function does not have a bang version, you could make a helper function to do something similar.

```rb
File.cwd()
|> ok!()
|> IO.puts()

defp ok!({:ok, value}), do: value
```

If you're 100% confident a function will return an ok tuple, you could use `elem/2` to get a value from the tuple. This isn't as explicit, so it's not my favorite.

```rb
File.cwd()
|> elem(1)
|> IO.puts()
```

That being said, control flow is not where piping exceeds. It does best if you're doing several operations to transform a data structure. For such a situation you're probably better off using logical constructs and breaking things up into smaller functions.

Comment: It’s worth to mention that [`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#with/1) has a monadic behavior and _returns_ non-matched results.

Comment: I'm going to accept this one because it offers several examples directly at the question. @AlekseiMatiushkin answer below really provides deeper insight  into the situation though. I appreciate you both. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There is no *idiomatic* way to pipe the second arg.

[elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) discourages using pipes in two cases:

- there are only two links in the chain
- the next function in the chain accepts the outcome of the previous function not as a first argument or the outcome provides something different from what the next function in the chain expects.

---

Whenever it makes sense, the core library does it’s best to provide all the sugar to make piping a charm. Consider tweaking strings. We have two `replace/4` functions: [`String.replace/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html?#replace/4) *and* [`Regex.replace/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html?#replace/4) with nearly similar functionality, but the former takes a string as a first argument to make it easier to pipe into chains when the string comes, and the latter accepts regex as a first argument.

If you find yourself in a bewilderment of how to pipe — it’s a clear sign you should not pipe. That simple, the language itself hints the best way to go. Indeed, nobody returns `{:ok, value}` from the function that always succeeds. That said, *there might be some other outcome*. In the case in the question, `{:error, reason}`. Let me guess: you don’t want your code to blow up on it. And [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) kindly reminds you about that. Of course, you still can pipe with [`Kernel.elem/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#elem/2), but do you really want to? I bet no.

There are at least two different approaches, depending on what do you actually want to achieve.

One would be to use a monadic [`SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#with/1), that either continues to execute clauses *or* returns the first non-matched result.

```rb
with {:ok, a} <- Mod.fun1(),
     {:ok, b} <- Mod.fun2(a),
     {:ok, c} <- Mod.fun3(b),
  do: IO.puts(c)
```

That way you either output `c` *or* return the first non-matched (read: errored) outcome.

Another way around would be to use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.case/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#case/2).

```rb
File.cwd()
|> case do
  {:ok, result} -> result
  {:error, reason} -> LOG_OR_SOMETHING
end
```

Pick up any of your choices, but remember: pipe should be used where it belongs, not everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print value to stdout you have few options but here are two closest to your example

```
File.cwd()
|> inspect()
|> IO.puts()
```

or you can use shorter version

```
File.cwd()
|> IO.inspect()
```

difference is that `IO.inspect/2` accepts any term and returns same term, while IO.puts() accept string and iolist and returns `:ok` or `{:error, ...}` so you need to cast value to string if you want to use IO.puts().